# Agrupar items mysql en una tabla html

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo una tabla:
en mi BD mysql llamada Llaves

| id | nombre | key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Liam | 10 |
| 2 | David | 10 |
| 3 | Alex | 5 |
| 4 | Daniel | 3 |
| 5 | Nathan | 5 |

Uso en php:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Llave</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
        $sql='SELECT * FROM llaves GROUP BY key';
        $res = $connect->query($sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
         echo <tr><td>...</td></tr>
        }
?>
</tbody>
<table>
```

Deseo que me agrupe las rows con el mismo KEY sin ser separadas asi:

| Llave |
| --- |
| Liam - David |
| Alex - Nathan |
| Daniel |

Pero me devuelve:

| Llave |
| --- |
| Liam |
| Alex |
| Daniel |

Lo que deseo es que me agrupe los nombres con la misma key sin ser separados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esto y mirate los comentarios. Si funciona y no lo entiendes me preguntas en los comentarios:

```php
// consultamos todos los registros
$sql = "SELECT * FROM llaves";

$res = $connect->query($sql);

// almacenamos todos los registros en un array multidimensional con las keys
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $llaves[$row['key']][] = $row['nombre'];
}

// Iniciamos la salida
$salidaHTML = '';

// recorremos el array 
foreach ($llaves as $key => $array_nombres) {
    $salidaHTML .= '<tr><td>'
    $nombres = '';
    // recorremos los nombres de esta key
    foreach ($array_nombres as $nombre) {
        $nombres .= $nombre . ' - ';
    }

    // eliminamos el guión que sobra
    $salidaHTML .= rtrim($nombres, "- ");
    $salidaHTML .= '</td></tr>'
}

// mostramos la salida
echo $salidaHTML;
```

**Cambios realizados**

Practicamente todo se ha cambiado, pero vamos uno a uno:

1. La consulta que tenia el OP en su pregunta no devolvia todos los nombres necesarios, por lo que he optado por hacerla de este modo para conseguir todos los registros con todos los datos:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM llaves";
```

2. Durante el recorrido de la consulta se ha creado un array muldimensional donde cada clave `key` contenia a su vez otro array con los nombres, de este modo:

```
$llaves[$row['key']][] = $row['nombre'];
```

Con esa sintaxis, se ha estado creando un array de este tipo:

```
$llaves = [
  [ key1 => [nombre1, nombre2, ...]],
  [ key2 => [nombre3, nombre4, ...]],
  ...
]
```

3. Ahora solo quedaba recorrer ese array mediante un doble bucle foreach() e ir generando la salida, de este modo:

```
foreach ($llaves as $key => $array_nombres) {
    $salidaHTML .= '<tr><td>'

    // inicializamos esta variable en cada key
    $nombres = '';

    // recorremos los nombres de esta key
    foreach ($array_nombres as $nombre) {
        $nombres .= $nombre . ' - ';
    }

    // eliminamos el guión que sobra del string $nombres
    $salidaHTML .= rtrim($nombres, "- ");

    $salidaHTML .= '</td></tr>'
}
```

El resto espero que se pueda entender en los comentarios del propio código.

Comment: Al principio no la entendi, pero cuando vi el foreach eh entendido todo... Gracias ^^

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro que te haya funcionado :-)  Más adelante, quizás hoy o mañana,  editaré la respuesta y agregaré un poco de explicación para los demás y que quede una buena respuesta. Saludos!

Comment: He agregado un poco de explicación por si aun tienes dudas puedas consultar. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias.........